# How to return null values on an inner join

Tags: sql-server

I wrote this query which returns the unique_ID and the max note number from a different table. The problem is that I also need it to also show the unique_ID for the note numbers that are null (I.E. has no max). Is this possible to do from this query? I've tried everything I can think of and this is as far is I've gotten.

```
SELECT
            q.[Unique ID]
            ,qn.[Note Number], qn.*, q.*
FROM
            Q_NOT_PROC  q
LEFT JOIN   QUEUE_NOTES qn ON qn.[Order Item UniqueID]  = q.[Unique ID]
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
            qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
            ,MAX(qn.[Note Number])  NoteNum
    FROM
            QUEUE_NOTES qn
    JOIN    Q_NOT_PROC  q ON q.[Unique ID]  = qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
    GROUP BY
            qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
) b ON  b.[Order Item UniqueID] = q.[Unique ID]
    AND b.NoteNum               = qn.[Note Number];
```

If it returns note num 6, then that also means there are note numbers 0-5. I just only want to see the max note number. I also need to see those with no notes (null)

What it currently returns:

`+-----------+----------+
| Unique_ID | Note Num |
+-----------+----------+
| U_ID1     |        6 |
| U_ID2     |        4 |
| U_ID3     |        2 |
+-----------+----------+`

What I need it to return:

`+-----------+----------+
| Unique_ID | Note Num |
+-----------+----------+
| U_ID1     | 6        |
| U_ID2     | 4        |
| U_ID3     | 2        |
| U_ID4     | null     |
| U_ID5     | null     |
+-----------+----------+`

Comment: Just change `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` when joining with the subquery?

Comment: It'll be really helpful if you can share a sample data table and expected the result from that data...

Comment: When you have two tables in your main query and the same two tables in a subquery it is a sign that something is very likely gone adrift. I am certain this can be greatly simplified but I just can't quite wrap my head around what you are trying to do here. Posting the ddl, sample data and desired output would be a HUGE help. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: If I change the join to left join, it no longer just gives me the MAX. It gives me all note numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Just change your `inner join` to `left join`

```
SELECT q.[Unique ID], b.[Note Number]
FROM Q_NOT_PROC q
LEFT JOIN QUEUE_NOTES qn
     ON qn.[Order Item UniqueID] = q.[Unique ID]
LEFT JOIN ( -- Do left join instead of inner join
       SELECT qn.[Order Item UniqueID] , MAX(qn.[Note Number]) NoteNum
       FROM QUEUE_NOTES qn
       JOIN Q_NOT_PROC q ON q.[Unique ID] = qn.[Order Item UniqueID]          
       GROUP BY qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
  ) b ON b.[Order Item UniqueID] = q.[Unique ID] AND 
         b.NoteNum = qn.[Note Number];
```

**Edit:** After *question* edit

```
SELECT Q.[Unique ID], b.NoteNum
FROM Q_NOT_PROC Q LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT [Order Item UniqueID] UniqueId, MAX([Note Number]) NoteNum
       FROM QUEUE_NOTES qn
       GROUP BY [Order Item UniqueID]) b ON b.UniqueId = Q.[Unique ID]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I would add that the first join to `QUEUE_NOTES` is pointless and should be deleted.

Comment: If I change the join to left join, it no longer just gives me the MAX. It gives me all note numbers.

Comment: @YogeshSharma, please see my edits on the question. I realized I left out that I needed qn.* on the query that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

`SELECT q.[Unique ID], qn.[Note Number], qn.*, q.*
  FROM Q_NOT_PROC qnp
  LEFT JOIN QUEUE_NOTES qn
  ON qn.[Order Item UniqueID] = qnp.[Unique ID]
   INNER JOIN (
    SELECT qn.[Order Item UniqueID] , MAX(qn.[Note Number]) NoteNum
    FROM QUEUE_NOTES qn
      JOIN Q_NOT_PROC qnp ON qnp.[Unique ID] = qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
    GROUP BY qn.[Order Item UniqueID]
) b ON b.[Order Item UniqueID] = qnp.[Unique ID]
  AND b.NoteNum = qn.[Note Number]
UNION ALL 
SELECT q.[Unique ID], qn.[Note Number], qn.*, q.*
  FROM Q_NOT_PROC qnp
  LEFT JOIN QUEUE_NOTES qn
  ON qn.[Order Item UniqueID] = qnp.[Unique ID]
    WHERE qn.[Note Number] IS NULL`